# Using rscript for expression with dash

Tags: r, rscript

I am using rscript to run some expressions but I'm having an issue with some cases with dashes. A simple example would be:

```
$ rscript -e '-1'
ERROR: option '-e' requires a non-empty argument
```

Adding parenthesis works out (`rscript -e (-1)`) but I'm not always sure that they will be properly parenthesized.

In the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.1/topics/Rscript) it says

> When using -e options be aware of the quoting rules in the shell used

So I tried using different quoting rules for bash, escaping the dashes or using single quotes but it still doesn't work.

```
$ rscript -e "\-1"
Error: unexpected input in "\"
Execution halted
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand one part here. "Expression" is something R can parse, ie:

```
$ R --slave -e '1+1'
[1] 2
$
```

What you hit with `-1` is a corner case. You can do

```
$ R --slave -e 'a <- -1; a'
[1] -1
$
```

or

```
$ R --slave -e 'print(-1)'
[1] -1
$
```

For actual argument parsing do you want an package like `docopt` (which I like and use a lot), or `getopt` (which I used before) or `optparse`.  All are on CRAN.

Comment: Ohh I see, but then what it says in the doc about properly quoting according to the shell used, what does it mean? I'll take a look at docopt as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: The 'proper quoting' usually refers to the arguments itself, you sometimes want strings there etc pp.